# Cognex Barcode SDK not scanning codes

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, barcode-scanner, cognex

**I have implemented Cognex cmbSDK completely in my app. And i'm using trial version. Key and everything is implemented correctly, When i click on button it opens camera and also displays the features but it is not scanning any type of code. Can you please help me why it is not working?**

**Here is my code:**

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
ReaderDevice.OnConnectionCompletedListener, ReaderDevice.ReaderDeviceListener,ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

private val permissionCode = 123
private val sdkKey: String = "My KEY"
private lateinit var readerDevice: ReaderDevice

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    readerDevice = ReaderDevice.getPhoneCameraDevice(this, CameraMode.NO_AIMER,
        PreviewOption.NO_ZOOM_BUTTON, null, sdkKey)
    readerDevice.setReaderDeviceListener(this)
    readerDevice.enableImage(true)
    readerDevice.enableImageGraphics(false)
    readerDevice.connect(this)
    enableSymbologies()

    btnScanBarcode.setOnClickListener{
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), permissionCode)
        }
        readerDevice.startScanning()
    }
}

override fun onConnectionCompleted(readerDevice: ReaderDevice?, error: Throwable?) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    if (error != null) {
        // ask for Camera Permission if necessary
        if (error is CameraPermissionException) ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
            permissionCode
        )
    }
}

override fun onAvailabilityChanged(readerDevice: ReaderDevice?) {
}

override fun onConnectionStateChanged(readerDevice: ReaderDevice?) {

}

override fun onReadResultReceived(readerDevice: ReaderDevice, results: ReadResults) {
    readerDevice.stopScanning()
    Toast.makeText(this, "Result Received. ${results.getResultAt(0).symbology}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    Log.d("barcode" ,"MY BARCODE RESULT: ")

    if (results.subResults != null && results.subResults.size > 0) {
        for (subResult in results.subResults) {
            createResultItem(subResult)
        }
    } else if (results.count > 0) {
        createResultItem(results.getResultAt(0))
    }
}

private fun createResultItem(result: ReadResult) {
    val item =
        HashMap<String, String>()
    if (result.isGoodRead) {
        item["resultText"] = result.readString
        val sym = result.symbology
        if (sym != null) item["resultType"] =
            result.symbology.getName() else item["resultType"] =
            "UNKNOWN SYMBOLOGY"
    } else {
        item["resultText"] = "NO READ"
        item["resultType"] = ""
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, item["resultText"], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if(requestCode == permissionCode){
        readerDevice.startScanning()
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}

private fun enableSymbologies(){
    readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.DATAMATRIX, true, object : OnSymbologyListener {
        override fun onSymbologyEnabled(
            reader: ReaderDevice,
            symbology: Symbology,
            enabled: Boolean,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e(
                this.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Failed to enable Symbology.DATAMATRIX"
            )
        }
    })
    readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.C128, true, object : OnSymbologyListener {
        override fun onSymbologyEnabled(
            reader: ReaderDevice,
            symbology: Symbology,
            enabled: Boolean,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e(
                this.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Failed to enable Symbology.C128"
            )
        }
    })
    readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.UPC_EAN, true, object : OnSymbologyListener {
        override fun onSymbologyEnabled(
            reader: ReaderDevice,
            symbology: Symbology,
            enabled: Boolean,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e(
                this.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Failed to enable Symbology.UPC_EAN"
            )
        }
    })
    readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.CODABAR, false, object : OnSymbologyListener {
        override fun onSymbologyEnabled(
            reader: ReaderDevice,
            symbology: Symbology,
            enabled: Boolean,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e(
                this.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Failed to disable Symbology.CODABAR"
            )
        }
    })
    readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.C93, false, object : OnSymbologyListener {
        override fun onSymbologyEnabled(
            reader: ReaderDevice,
            symbology: Symbology,
            enabled: Boolean,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e(
                this.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Failed to disable Symbology.C93"
            )
        }
    })
    readerDevice.dataManSystem
        .sendCommand(
            "GET DEVICE.TYPE"
        ) { _, response ->
            if (response.error == null) {
                Log.d("Device type", response.payLoad)
            }
        }
    readerDevice.dataManSystem
        .sendCommand(
            "GET DEVICE.FIRMWARE-VER"
        ) { _, response ->
            if (response.error == null) {
                Log.d("Firmware version", response.payLoad)
            }
        }
}}
```

**Manifest File Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="MX_MOBILE_LICENSE"
        android:value="HERE I PUT MY KEY"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I've followed your code... what is the solution to read the barcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also if you see in our SDK we put this in configureReaderDevice ( here you put your symbology ) and then you call it from onConnectionStateChanged

But please open Support Ticket on this link and our Technical Support will resolved your issue - https://cmbdn.cognex.com/tickets

Enable the symbology have to be added after you connect to the readerDevice

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you please be more specific about the code that you like to scan because from the code I can see that you selected only UPC_EAN, DATAMATRIX, and C128 ( also see if this symbology is enabled in your license key )
2. All symbologies used for the symbology parameter in this method can be found in ReaderDevice.java.

Examples
readerDevice.setSymbologyEnabled(Symbology.QR, true, null);

3. Here is our Knowledge Base for more information - https://cmbdn.cognex.com/v2.3.x/knowledge/cognex-mobile-barcode-sdk-for-android/using-cmbsdk
4. You can always open a ticket on the Cognex webpage.

Best Regards,
Cognex Mobile Solutions Team